# UPDATE SQL query with base64 encoded data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

For one my application, I need to keep image files in database table. I am using AJAX to send the multi-part form data and can view the image file details on action page.

On action page, base64 encoding is working and showing the correct encoded data. Also, I saw the encoded data is showing on UPDATE SQL query by echoing the SQL statement.

But while trying to execute the SQL query statement then every time its only inserting `data:image/;base64,` and ignoring the base64 encoded full data.

When I submit the form without using AJAX then the system update the database table with base64 encoded data.

Sample code:
JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("change", "#bird", function() {

  var file_data = $("#bird").prop("files")[0]; 
  var form_data = new FormData(); 
  form_data.append("file", file_data)

  $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: image_data, 
        url: "/update-bird.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        cache:false,
        success: function(data) {
          // Ajax             
        }
   });
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES))
{
    $path = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    $birdpic = "data:image/".pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION).";base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

    $updateQ = "UPDATE birds SET picture='$birdpic' WHERE name='Yoy'";

    if($dbo->query($updateQ))
        echo 1;
    else
        echo 0;
 }
```

I hope, will get some advice to solve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's picture type and length in your table ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one - Table column must be `BLOB` or `LONGBLOB`

```
$img_data = file_get_contents($img_path);
$type = pathinfo($img_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$birdpic = base64_encode($img_data);
$updateQ = "UPDATE birds SET picture='$birdpic' WHERE name='Yoy'";
```

Comment: Thanks! My same code working as expected while submitting the form in normal way with image file but that does not work while submitting through AJAX. After echoing UPDATE SQL then found encoded code exist in the query. From my investigation, I found INSERT is working fine but on UPDATE its just ignoring the encoded portion of the string.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX will not carry the image file, try to use Jquery or submit the form.
Form with enctype="multipart/form-data", I not sure Jquery will work.